# Most Pythonic Replacement for .keys() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, refactoring

I've been looking into converting my Python 2.7 project to 3.
I'm discovered that I've been mostly using .keys() unnecessary as

```
for x in d:
```

has the same effect as

```
for in in d.keys():
```

However I have also learned that you can't shouldn't mutate a dictionary while iterating through it. This hasn't come up as I have been using Python2.7's .keys() which creates a copy of the dictionary's keys as a list. Python 3's version of .keys() creates a view rather than a copy so isn't usable for the same purpose.

2to3 translates d.keys() to list(d.items()) but I don't strictly need the keys in a list.
I have seen d.copy().keys() suggested but I don't see why the (Python 3) .keys() bit is necessary.

In the Python Docs it says

> It is safe to modify the values of the keys as you iterate over the
>   dictionary, but only so long as the set of keys does not change

So does 'mutating' only refer to changing keys then? Mostly I only alter dictionary values when iterating but I have found somewhere where there is a chance of the current key being deleted

So basically do I need to replace .keys() with anything and if so what is the most pythonic/efficient option?

The specific code (part of my implementation for repeating effects/damage-over-time in an adventure game/interactive fiction engine) is thus:

```
def Age(beats) :
    actions = []
    for echo in echoes.keys() :
        echoes[echo]['elapsed'] += beats
        activations = echoes[echo]['elapsed']/echoes[echo]['interval']
        while activations >= 1 :
            actions.append(str(echoes[echo]['action']))
            echoes[echo]['elapsed'] -= echoes[echo]['interval']
            activations = echoes[echo]['elapsed']/echoes[echo]['interval']
            try :
                echoes[echo]['reps'] -= 1
                if echoes[echo]['reps'] < 1 :
                    del echoes[echo]
                    break
            except TypeError : #Will be raised if reps is Infinite
                pass
    char['Echoes'] = echoes
    char.write()
    return actions
```

Yeh I probably commit all kinds of style guide sins here alone. I'm self-taught and discovered all the good practice stuff too late for this project. Sorry if I make your eyes bleed.

Comment: Mutating a dictionary (adding/removing keys) is indeed different from mutating a value mapped to a particular key. It's only the first thing you should avoid while iterating over its keys.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
Yeh it seems like for the most part I can harmlessly remove all the .keys() and then run 2to3 to fix the prints and raw_inputs. However in this particular instance if an 'echo' exhausts it's repetitions, it will be deleted. Does it matter that it would be the current key being deleted or should that still be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a list of keys that need to be removed and then remove them after you finish the loop:

```
def Age(beats):
    to_remove = []
    actions = []
    for echo in echoes.keys():
        echoes[echo]['elapsed'] += beats
        activations = echoes[echo]['elapsed']/echoes[echo]['interval']
        while activations >= 1 :
            actions.append(str(echoes[echo]['action']))
            echoes[echo]['elapsed'] -= echoes[echo]['interval']
            activations = echoes[echo]['elapsed']/echoes[echo]['interval']
            try :
                echoes[echo]['reps'] -= 1
                if echoes[echo]['reps'] < 1 :
                    to_remove.append(echo)
                    break
            except TypeError : #Will be raised if reps is Infinite
                pass
    for echo in to_remove:
        del echoes[echo]
    char['Echoes'] = echoes
    char.write()
    return actions
```

I also think its slightly more readable to use `.items()`:

```
for echo, value in echoes.items():
    value['elapsed'] += beats
    ...
```

Comment: I discovered .items() recently and figured I would go through after I had converted to 3 and find places where it would be useful.
You're right - this is a great place for .items(). I only really need the key itself if it gets deleted. Using the value (a sub dictionary actually) I can make things much more concise.

I thought of the list-to-be-deleted-later method but I thought it would be kind of ugly but as you've put it, it's actually a pretty elegant solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen d.copy().keys() suggested but I don't see why the (Python
>   3) .keys() bit is necessary.

You aren't reading it closely enough. Since `d.copy().keys()` creates a copy of the dictionary then creates keys from that copy it is essentially pointing to a new "view" of the dictionary and the keys.

This is essentially what it was doing in python 2.7 so it can be used for your purposes.

So in python 2.7 a new list is created directly from the dict and is returned whereas python 3 is pointing to the keys of that dict directly meaning that if it changes during iteration it will throw and error.

A different way that you can solve this in python 3 is doing:

```
for x in list(d):
```

since this returns a "new" list which won't change size during iteration.

Comment: I understand what d.copy().keys() is doing. However wouldn't d.copy() alone be sufficient?
If 'for x in d' iterates through the original dictionary's keys then wouldn't 'for x in d.copy()' iterate through the copy's keys? I don't need the keys to be in a list which is what the .keys() part does.

Comment: @ThomasSturges-AllardZig13 Yeah you are right! `d.copy()` is perfectly acceptable.